# Output of Serial is completely wrong -> what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, arduino

since the output of my code is completely weird (for me) I'd really appreciate any help!

I have to classes: `sensor` and `automation`. Objects of the sensor class hold all informations about this sensor (I removed a lot of code to reduce it to the current problem). The automation class will check all sensors and react depending on the measurements.
The sensor object is stored in automation to reduce the used RAM memory.

```
class sensor {

 public:

 // Constructor
 sensor(const char* sensorName) {
    // Store name in object
    setName(sensorName);
 }

 void addGroup(int newGroup) {
    for (int i=0; i <= (5); i++){ // Max. 5 groups
      if(groups[i] == 0) {
        groups[i] = newGroup;
        break;
      }
    }
 }


 int* getGroups() {
   return groups;
 }

 bool getIsObject() {
   return isObject;
 }

 char* getName() {
   return name;
 }

  void setName(const char* sensorName) {
    strcpy(name, sensorName); // Copy sensorName to name

    // Alternative:
    /*
    char i=0;

    do{
        name[i] = sensorName[i];
        ++i;
    }while(sensorName[i]!=0); //since a cstring is always null terminated.

    name[i] = 0;
    */
  }

 void setObject() {
    isObject = true;
 }

  private:

  int groups[5] = {0}; // Default group for all: 0
  bool isObject = false;
  char name [20]; // Max. 20 characters in name
};



class automation {
 public:

   automation() {
   }

  void run() {
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        Serial.println("Printing sensor information");
        Serial.print("Name: ");
        Serial.println(sensors[i]->getName());
        Serial.println("Group: ");
        Serial.println(sensors[0]->getGroups()[i]);
      }
   }//function


 // Füge Sensor-Instanz zu Sensor-Liste hinzu, um schlussendlich auf alle Sensoren zugreifen zu können
 int storeSensor(sensor *newSensor) {
   newSensor->setObject(); // Setze Variable isObject in Sensor-Instanz auf true
   int n = 0;
   for (int i=0; i < (sizeof(sensors)/sizeof(newSensor)-1); i++)
   {
     n=i;
     if(!sensors[i]->getIsObject()) {
       sensors[i] = newSensor;
       break;
     }
   }
   return n; // Liefert Array-Index / Stelle in Array, an der der Sensor gespeichert wurde.
 }



 private:
 sensor *sensors[5]; // Max. 5 sensors in the array

};

automation automation;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Serial interface started");


  sensor moistureSensor("moistureSensor");
  moistureSensor.addGroup(1);
  moistureSensor.addGroup(3);

  automation.storeSensor(&moistureSensor);
}


void loop() {
  Serial.println("Start loop()");
  automation.run();
  delay(2000);
}
```

The output of Serial.println() in automation:run() is:

```
Printing sensor information
Name: 
Group: 
255
Printing sensor information
Name: 
Group: 
20480
Printing sensor information
Name: 
Group: 
10
```

So the groups don't match to the added groups and the sensor name is empty. Why?!

Comment: I don't have time to write up a proper answer right now, but two immediate concerns are that 1. the lifetime of `moistureSensor` ends when the `setup()` function ends (the program is likely reusing the bytes pointed at by `&moistureSensor` - reading is harmless but also meaningless, but writing could be disastrous). And 2. `if(!sensors[i]->getIsObject())` you are dereferencing unitialized memory. There's no telling what `sensors[0]` points to when  you first call `storeSensor`, because we don't know what the value of `sensors[0]` is, and if we did it hasn't been set aside for a sensor.

Comment: Oh man. Point 1 is so simple.... thanks! But I don't get your second point. For my understanding the following should happen: By default `sensor:isObject` is `false`. If `automation:storeSensor()` is called, all present sensors stored in `sensors` array are checked if their `isObject` is false. If so, the `isObject` of the new sensor should be set to `true`. Even sensor[0] could be checked for this in my understanding. Or what am I misunderstanding? And what do you mean with "dereferencing initialized memory"?

Comment: When you construct `automation` by calling `automation automation` (btw name the class `Automation` instead so readers can tell the object apart from the class) the member `sensor *sensors[5]` is constructed - space is set aside for five `sensor *` objects. But only the pointers. No space has been set aside for the `sensor` objects you want these `sensor *` to point to.

Comment: How does dynamic memory allocation work on Arduino? I read there's no `new` keyword, and the STL doesn't come standard. If you can use an STL implementation, use `vector` and `string` instead of arrays and `char *`. Otherwise, you could initialize `sensors` to be an array of `sensor`s, instead of an array of `sensor *`s. (this will increase the size of the `automation` object, but you have to store the `sensor`s somewhere anyway. Again, not an expert on memory management for Arduino.

Comment: What are the advantages of `vector` and `string` compared to `arrays` and `char *`? 
The best solution right now is to declare `sensors` as array of `sensor` - I already used this but it overfilled my RAM so I changed it to an array of `sensor*` (of course this reduced it but I didn't see the point of the lifetime).
Is there a possibility to not store this array in the RAM but in the FLASH and only get the elements when they're needed?

Comment: If you need to dynamically allocate memory, `vector` and `string` will handle that for you, and free their resources on destruction, preventing very-easy-to-make memory errors in your code. They're dynamic in size, with memory being allocated on the fly. You may not know at compile time that user has a `string` of size 25. They also offer a very nice iteration interface so that moving through the containers is idiomatic. It leads to cleaner, easier to maintain code. The downside is a few bytes of overhead.

Comment: Looks like Arduino allows you to specify certain data in PROGMEM, which will keep it in flash. This requires further special functions to access it. The thing is that flash isn't good for data that needs to be written to during runtime, since rewriting a byte in flash requires copying the whole page to memory, resetting the page in flash, and writing back the old page with the byte changed. Writes to flash are therefore expensive. The only real candidates I see in your code for using PROGMEM are the string literals in your `Serial.print` statements.

Comment: Unfortunately your sensor has to exist SOMEWHERE in memory, and since it's modified at runtime, it has to be in RAM. What's `groups[5]` used for? Maybe this could be decreased in size to a `uint8_t` depending on how you're identifying your groups. Also, instead of each `sensor` tracking whether it's an object or not, you make `Automation` keep track of the current number of sensors in its array using another `uint8_t sensors_size`. When you add a new sensor, assign it to the current `sensors_size` index of `sensors` and increment the counter. That should save 16 bytes per `sensor`.

Comment: It looks like you can easily wrap your string literals in the letter `F` function e.g. `Serial.println(F("This string will be stored in flash memory"));` if you're using Arduino IDE 1.0 or higher. Based on the code you've shown that will save about 100 bytes of RAM. https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Memory/

Comment: Thanks for these very detailed hints / suggestions.
Using `vector` and `string` sounds quite interesting, I'll try that. I'm already using `PROGMEM` and the `F()` function in my `debug()` function, but I removed this and replaced it to direct `Serial.println()` calls - but good advice.
`groups[5]` is used for linking controls to the sensors (same group -> sensor measures, control does something). I'll check that `uint8_t` thing - I never saw that.
Why should using a tracking within `Automation` save 16 bytes per `sensor` - it's only one `bool` value -> 1 byte?

Comment: You can wrap function calls. So `Serial.println("This is a string");` should be replaced by `Serial.println(F("This is a string"));`. I assumed that `int` was 32 bits on arduino. According to this it's actually 16 bits (2 bytes) https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/. So your `int groups[5]` array holds  10 bytes (I thought it held 20).  If you change it to `std::uint8_t groups[5];` then it will only hold 5 bytes. A savings of 5 bytes per sensor (I thought it was 15 before).

Comment: I can't use `uint8_t` due to this error: `'uint8_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>` usually fixes that. I forgot that not every compiler automatically includes it.

Comment: I didn't know that's a "default" library which is shipped with the compiler - I searched it in the Arduino library management and didn't find it so I assumed it's not available for Arduino. But I can directly `include` it, so I will use it. Thanks again for your support!